# Configure MC and aptitude color schemes

Tags: colors, aptitude, mc

I'm using Ubuntu, and I'm having trouble reading text in MC and Aptitude because of the color scheme. Is there any way to change it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe a quick fix: `mc -b` forces no-color mode `;)`

You can write your own skins for `mc`, which include a color scheme. They live in `~/.mc/skins` and are selected by `mc -S skinname`. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508153346/http://blog.mybox.ro:80/2010/05/10/skins-and-color-themes-for-midnight-commander/) talks a bit about it and has [an example available for download](https://web.archive.org/web/20120919033555/http://blog.mybox.ro:80/wp-content/files/ovidiu.ini) at the end.

But maybe the deeper trouble is that your term background is "not the expected color", so another way would be to change how your term displays the 16 "standard colors". (For example, this would make all formerly-green items purple, if that's better for you from a contrast standpoint.) How this is done depends on your terminal emulator, for example XFCE's Terminal has it in its preferences dialog, for xterm you probably need to edit a configuration file etc.

Comment: Link seams to be dead. Adding an example directly to the answer would be nice.

Comment: Q idea how to start nocolor by default?

Comment: `alias mc="mc -b"` in your terminal or your login script.

Answer (score 8):

From the changelog:

> Version 4.8.0-pre1
>
> WARNING: Configuration files was moved from your $HOME/.mc directory into
> XDG_CONFIG_* directories to respect FDO standard
> (http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.7.html)

`mcedit .config/mc/ini`
search for `skin` with <kbd>F7</kbd>
`skin=modarin256` is really nice for example :)
Look into `/usr/share/mc/skins/` to see the different themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own color theme for Aptitude. There is even [nice documentation](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s03.en.html).

As was already said in accepted answer, deeper trouble is in fact that colors are depending on each other, so there is standard terminal color theme you are using and ncurses app theme is build upon that. Thus i.e. aptitude have different "blue" then you may expect.

Here is my *yellow/black* style, which I design to be high contrast and used with [base16_materia](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-xresources/blob/master/xresources/base16-materia-256.Xresources) terminal theme:

```
aptitude::UI::Styles "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBar "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBar::bg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBar::fg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::HighlightedMenuBar "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::HighlightedMenuBar::fg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::HighlightedMenuBar::bg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::Header "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::Header::bg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::Header::fg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::Status "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::Status::bg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::Status::fg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::DisabledMenuEntry "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::DisabledMenuEntry::fg "white";
aptitude::UI::Styles::DisabledMenuEntry::bg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuEntry "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuEntry::fg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuEntry::bg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder::fg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MenuBorder::bg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::HighlightedMenuEntry "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::HighlightedMenuEntry::bg "yellow";
aptitude::UI::Styles::HighlightedMenuEntry::fg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MultiplexTab "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MultiplexTab::bg "cyan";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MultiplexTab::fg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MultiplexTabHighlighted "";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MultiplexTabHighlighted::bg "black";
aptitude::UI::Styles::MultiplexTabHighlighted::fg "yellow";
```

Just add it to the end of `~/.aptitude/config` file.

Comment: You mean, add a file `/etc/apt/conf.d/01aptitude-local.conf`.